# After charging the permissions, why can't you execute a .run shell lscript from the terminal in ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: command-line, scripts, 13.04

You used to double-click and it would ask you if you wanted to open it in the text editor or run in the terminal.
Now I have to open the terminal myself and type the appropriate shell command.

Answer (score 3):

Nautilus> Preferences>Go to Behaviour tab > Click the radio button near Ask each time. This will solve your issue(ensure that the permissions have been given).

Answer (score 2):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences executable-text-activation ask
```